# In a dual core processor, Do both the processors halt execution when an interrupt occurs?

Tags: cpu, multi-core, interrupts

suppose two cores of a CPU are running two threads parallelly, and an interrupt occurs one on of them, does the other processor also stop execution ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find more information in this article: **[Why interrupt affinity with multiple cores is not such a good thing](http://www.alexonlinux.com/why-interrupt-affinity-with-multiple-cores-is-not-such-a-good-thing)**

> Every x86 motherboard has a chip
>   called IO-APIC. This is a device that
>   controls interrupt delivery within
>   your system. It knows how many CPUs
>   are in your system and can direct
>   various interrupts to various CPUs. It
>   uses so called local APIC-ID as an
>   identifier of the processor.
>
> It has **two modes of operation**. In
>   one mode it sends **interrupts from
>   certain device to single, predefined
>   core**. This mode of operation called
>   fixed/physical mode. In another mode,
>   it can deliver **interrupts from
>   certain device to multiple cores**.
>   The later mode called logical/low
>   priority interrupt delivery mode.

See also this patent from IBM: [**Interrupt dispatching method in multi-core environment and multi-core processor**](http://www.freshpatents.com/-dt20091001ptan20090248934.php)